# Infinite Sequence of Coin Tossings

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, independence

I have a question about an exercise problem from Durrett's probability book and its solution sketch in the solution manual.

On page 53, 2.1.18, it says

"If we want an infinite sequence of coin tossings, we do not have to use Kolmogorov's theorem. Let $\Omega$ be the unit interval $(0,1)$ equipped with the Borel set $\mathcal{F}$ and Lebesgue measure P. Let $Y_n(\omega) = 1 $ if $[2^n \omega]$ is odd and $0$ if $[ 2^n\omega]$ is even. Show that $Y_1, Y_2, ...$ are independent with $P(Y_k=0)=P(Y_k=1)=1/2.$"

In the solution manual, the solution is given in two lines as follows:

Let $i_1, i_2, ...\in \{0,1\}$ and $x = \sum_{m=1}^n i_m 2^{-m}$, then

$P(Y_1 = i_1,..., Y_n = i_n) =P(\omega \in [x,x+2^{-n})) = 2^{-n}.  \quad*$

I understand that this solves the problem, but I cannot see how to justify the first equation in $*$. Could someone give a hint?

Note: To my knowledge, $[2^n \omega]$ is defined by $[x] = \max\{a \in \mathbb{Z}, a \leq x\}$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}.$

Comment: What first equation? The choice of $x$? It is just a rational number, finite series, so no justification needed. Regardless of what the bracket notation means, it should be clear that it is meant to take the $n$th digit is the binary decimal expansion of $x$.

Comment: Edited the question so that what I mean by the first equation is now clear.

Comment: I have a question in the other direction: I understand the result of $2^{-n}$, however, I do not see how it implies that each probability is $2^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, note that $x$ is a rational number with the specified binary expansion given by the $i_n$. What we want is all numbers who share those first $n$ digits in their binary expansion. Adding $2^{-n}$ will increment the $n$th digit in the expansion, but adding anything less than $2^{-n}$ will keep the first $n$ digits the same as $x$. Thus the interval we are interested in is $[x, x+2^{-n} )$, i.e. $\omega \in [x, x+2^{-n} )$ then the binary decimal expansion of $\omega$ has the first $n$ digits identical to those of $x$. The uniform probability of this is just the length of the interval.

Does that help? I can elaborate further if necessary.

Comment: It is clear now, thanks.

Comment: I'm glad you found my explanation helpful.

Comment: Can you explain more on this? Why this related to the fact that if $[2^n\omega]$ is even or odd?

Comment: @Heydude do you have a specific question? $[2^n\omega]$ is either even or odd.